# XCode5 Error: "use of undeclared identifier uistatusbarstylelightcontent" iOS6 deployment

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios7, xcode5

I've been working on a project where the deployment target is iOS 6 but the Build Settings/Base SDK is iOS 7.  I was returning UIStatusBarStyleLightContent from (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle and the project was compiling.

I tried wrapping the offending code in compiler #if statements like this:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle 
{ 
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 70000
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;'
#else
    return UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
#endif
}
```

But then I got the same error for other identifiers like 'tintColor' and 'cornerRadius' for CALayers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I was searching for an accidentally changed project setting, but I couldn't find any and my .xcuserdata is in my git ignore file.  I added the iOS 6.1 SDK to my XCode 5 installation to compile another test app to my iOS 6 test device last night, so I tried removing that folder from XCode 5's library.  Even though I wasn't explicitly targeting the iOS 6 SDK (it was my Deployment Target not Base SDK) XCode was looking at my code as if it was iOS 6 and throwing errors for all my iOS 7 code.